# Why can't I delete messages from my IMAP account on my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email, trash

I have an iPhone 4 and have set up mail with an IMAP account. When I delete a message a popup says **Unable to move message - The message could not be moved to the trash folder**.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe the trash folder is not correctly set on your iPhone.

Depending on the email-provider, you may have to choose the correct "deleted" folder in your account settings on the iPhone.

(maybe the translations are not literally, i am using a German iPhone):
Go to "Settings" -> "Mail, contacts ...", choose your IMAP account, choose "account info", look at the bottom and choose "advanced".

Here you can choose which folder is your trash folder.

Comment: [This option is not available in iOS 10.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/257734/4395)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem deleting an email that said "this message has not been downloaded from server." I couldn't move it to Trash either, even after affirming the prompt to "download message from server." I finally forwarded it to myself and was prompted to download message before sending. I answered yes. I then deleted the forwarded message and the original troublesome message and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the following fixed it on my iphone 6.

go to mail
then mailboxes
find "trash" and make sure the box is checked.

Solved my problem.